# Update returned value from db to make it loopable

Tags: python

I want to add brackets to

```
db_value = "[" + db.session.execute(sql).fetchone() + "]"
```

or

```
db_value = "{" + db.session.execute(sql).fetchone() + "}"
```

This is what I get:

> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'RowProxy' objects

`print(db_value)` prints out `(121, u'', "John Lennon", 1940, u'Beatles', datetime.date(1940, 9, 9)...)`

I want to make the returned value as `[(121, u'', "John Lennon", 1940, u'Beatles', datetime.date(1940, 9, 9)...), (222, u'', Elton John"...)]` to easily loop through it.

Comment: Does this work? `"[" + str(db.session.execute(sql).fetchone()) + "]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't make data structures by concatenating strings. You just use the literal syntax.

```
db_value = [db.session.execute(sql).fetchone()]
```